# RunOnUiThread fails to load, An object reference is required (android)

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I have 2 classes one called "Activity1" and the second "JS2CS". In the JS2C I am trying to update a android widget (SwipeRefreshLayout) that I declared in the Activity1, I need the widget to be static (just in case this is important).

Here is the short version of the Activity1

```
public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
     public static SwipeRefreshLayout refresher;

     protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
        base.OnCreate (bundle); 
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource             
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // The refresher - SwipeRefreshLayout
        refresher = FindViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout> (Resource.Id.refresher);
        refresher.SetColorScheme (Resource.Color.xam_dark_blue,
            Resource.Color.xam_purple,
            Resource.Color.xam_gray,
            Resource.Color.xam_green);
        refresher.Refresh += HandleRefresh;

        }

    }
```

And here is the second class JS2CS

```
public class JS2CS : Java.Lang.Object, Java.Lang.IRunnable
        {
            Context context;

            public JS2CS (Context context)
            {
                this.context = context;
            }

            public void Run ()
            {
                Toast.MakeText (context, "true", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
                Activity1.RunOnUiThread (() => refresher.Enabled = false); // <-- error !               
            }
        }
```

So debugging this code as it is returns an "An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property " error.

I am calling the "JS2CS" class as java library for the webview (this is located in the onCreate of Activity1), just in case this is needed :

```
        web_view = FindViewById<WebView> (Resource.Id.webview);
        web_view.SetWebViewClient (new webLinks ());
        web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        web_view.AddJavascriptInterface (new JS2CS (this), "JS2CS");
```

I am using xamarin (c#), but answers on both languages (c# and java) is fine by me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where you are using `JS2CS` in onCreate?

Comment: It is on the same activity and I call it as java library for the webview I will update the post to show this. Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or
>   property "

Because here `Activity1.RunOnUiThread` you are trying to access `non-static` method `RunOnUiThread` from `Activity` without using instance.

Instead of creating Object or accessing View's in static way from  `Activity1` parameterized `JS2CS` class constructor to get all values:

```
Activity activity;
SwipeRefreshLayout refresher
public JS2CS (Context context,Activity activity,
                                      SwipeRefreshLayout refresher)
   {
     this.context = context;
     this.activity=activity;
     this.refresher=refresher;
   }
```

Now call `RunOnUiThread` as:

```
activity.RunOnUiThread (() => refresher.Enabled = false);
```

And in activity pass `JS2CS` object to `AddJavascriptInterface` method as:

```
web_view.AddJavascriptInterface (new JS2CS (this,this,refresher),"JS2CS");
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, good answer with explanation to the reason of the error, I definitely learned something new today thanks to you.